# list database, collection and the number of document in batch mode

Tags: list, mongodb, collections, batch-processing

I started my MongoDB journey with the follow questions:

1. How to list all databases in MongoDB?
2. How to list all collections in a specific database?
3. How to list the number of documents in a specific collection?

The answers I found are as below:

1. show dbs
2. use `<db name>`
         show collections
3. use `<db name>`
         db.`<collection name>`.count()

All commands above were run in MongoDB shell manually.  I would like to find a way to run these commands in a batch mode and get the results formatted like:

Would anyone like to share any ideas implementing it?
Any specific snippet would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can basically just create a JavaScript file and run it through the mongo shell if you want:

```js
var db = db.getSiblingDB("admin");

var output = [];
db.runCommand({ listDatabases: 1 }).databases.map(
  function(x){ return x.name }
).forEach(function(dbname) {
  var cdb = db.getSiblingDB(dbname);
  cdb.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(coll) {
    var count = cdb.getCollection(coll).count();
    output.push({
      db: cdb,
      collection: coll,
      count: count
    });
  })
});

printjson( output );
```

And then just invoke it. I called the file "lister.js":

```js
mongo lister.js
```

So you can use the `print()` or `printjson()` methods that are available to the shell to produce output how you want.

Otherwise consult the MongoDB driver for your favorite scripting language and implement something along the lines of what is shown above. All the basic methods and principles will be available.